# In one case shared_ptr cause runtime error, in another doesn't

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers

Why

```
struct X{};

X x;
X *q = &x;
std::shared_ptr<X> p(&x);
```

causes error and

```
X x;
X *q = &x;
std::shared_ptr<X> p0 = std::make_shared<X>(x);
```

doesn't cause runtime error?

I read that in the first case I have "two different pointers, pointing to the same data and one of them is shared"

But I think that there is the same situation in the second case?

### runtime error

```
free(): invalid pointer
```

Comment: `shared_ptr` has a slightly confusing name; it's not a shared *pointer*, but a (pointer to a) shared *object* - the ownership of that object is shared between all `shared_ptr`s that hold a pointer to it, and there can be no other owners of it.

Comment: The important difference is that `make_shared<X>(x)` creates a copy of `x` (that the `shared_ptr` then has ownership of) whereas the first case assumes ownership of `x` directly.

Comment: Note that the "make" in "make_shared" is creational as in "make me a pizza", not transformational as in "make me a millionaire".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the first case, the object `x` is deleted although it's lifetime already ends with the end of its scope. Here, you create an instance on the stack and in your scope :

```
X x; // lifetime automatically ends at the end of the scope
```

Then, you ask the `std::shared_ptr` to control the lifetime of the address of `x`, too.

```
std::shared_ptr<X> p(&x); // calls delete at the end of the scope
```

Hence, you free the same variable twice, which is undefined behavior. In the second case, you create a `std::shared_ptr` to a copied instance that is independent of the `x` instance.

```
std::shared_ptr<X> p0 = std::make_shared<X>(x); // Copies x, then deletes the copy
```

This is no problem, as both objects are only deleted once.

Note the semantics of `std::make_shared` here: the arguments you pass to it are forwarded to the constructor of its template argument. Hence you trigger the compiler-generated copy constructor `X(const X&)` to be invoked. This is very different from creating a `std::shared_ptr` from an already existing pointer to via `std::shared_ptr p(&x);`.

Comment: It's not deleted twice, it's only deleted once, but it should not be deleted at all because it's an automatic variable on the stack. Stack variables aren't deleted, they're just destroyed.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Thanks, I hope the wording is correct now.

Answer (score 7):

In the first case, `p` takes ownership of `x`. When `p` goes out of scope, it deletes `x`. But `x` was not dynamically allocated. Oops.

You don't have that situation in the second case. The `make_shared` function dynamically allocates a new, shared object. When `p0` goes out of scope, it destroys that newly-created object. Note that, in this case, `*p0` is not `x` but the new object.